# Passing a random Object to a function

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a few different objects (different classes) that I need to pass as parameter to the same function. I'm not sure how to define my function here. should I just do "Object obj" as parameter or is there a better way using reflection or  Generics?

```
public void Execute (string query, Object obj) {}
```

EDIT:

Using @Lame_coder Idea, I made my Base classe implement an Interface having a fct GetStringParmeters() that uses reflexion (instead of each class having it's own GetStringParmeters() fct)

```
public Dictionary<string,string> GetStringParmeters()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Type obj = this.GetType();            
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetProperties())
        {
            if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {                    
                parameters.Add(prop.Name, (string)prop.GetValue(this, null));
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }
```

Thanks all

Comment: There's a better way using [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: What are you going to do with that parameter?

Comment: How are you using that object afterwards?

Comment: One thing to ask yourself is WHY are you passing in many different types, you really don't want to end up with a method that checks to see if your object (generic or otherwise) is of a certain type. That tells you probably want be looking at different ways of achieving your goals.

Comment: @Servy, Yes, I wanna loop over that object (using reflection) to get all the strings

Comment: @ElieEl-Tawil So it's important that the object be a collection of strings, and not any type of object?

Comment: @Servy, I added an example of what my objects look like...if it helps.

Comment: @ElieEl-Tawil What matters is what this method is doing, and what they need to know about the parameter.  Seeing one example object passed in isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Servy, the method takes a SQL query in and an Object from which Ill extract the strings (using reflection or as proposed from other people via an interface) to plug in the SQL query

Comment: @ElieEl-Tawil Do all of the objects share a base type or interface with the needed information?  Can they be refactored to have one if they currently don't?

Comment: @Servy Yes there is a base class. I'm actually trying out what Lame_coder proposed (creating an Interface and have the Base class implement that Interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked "is there a better way using reflection?"

From the example method signature you have given it looks like reflection would be an overkill. You should create an inteface as @drazmazen have suggested and implement in the types you are expecting to pass in. You can have a common method say 'getParameters' which you can implement in implementation of you interface which in turn can be used by your method.

```
public interface IMother
{
   string[] GetParameters();
}

public class ChildOne:IMother
{
   public string[] GetParameters()
   {
     //build output
     return;
   }
}
public class ChildTwo:IMother
{
   public string[] GetParameters()
   {
     //build output
     return;
   }
}
```

ANd then your execute method could be

```
public void Execute (string query, IMother obj) 
{
   //get needed information
   var queryParams = obj.GetParameters();

   //use it further for your code.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Generics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). That way, you can re-use this method for multiple object types without creating overloads.

```
public void Execute<T>(string query, T obj)
{
}
```

Comment: **Moderator Note**: If you'd like to discuss C# and its particulars, we have [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) for that. If you need specific clarification from the OP; please ask for that.  If you'd like to debate whether it's a good approach, feel free to answer with your own competing approach, or head to one of the aforementioned chatrooms.

Answer (score 2):

Depends really on your use case. You could do one of a few things:

- Your classes could, if it is possible, inherit from a mother class and then your method could take the parent class as a parameter
- Similarly, your classes could perhaps implement the same interface - IMyInterface, and then the method can take objects of type IMyInterface as arguments
- use Generics and redefine your method accordingly

Like I said, it really depends on what exactly you need to do.